# Can I get keyCode(num) from Sql but map value(String) to an object?

Tags: spring, mybatis

My problem like this:

I'm using the following setup:

- mybatis 3.4.2
- springframework 4.3.3
- mysql 5.7

My table in MySql is

```
CREATE TABLE `account_info` (
   `account_id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `account_holder_id` char(64) NOT NULL,
   `account_number` char(19) NOT NULL,
   `account_type` int(2) DEFAULT NULL 
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

What I want is to `account_type` field mapping like `(1:"debit", 2:"credit", 3:"affiliated",  ...)`

My java class

```
public class AccountInfo {
    private Integer accountId;
    private String accountHolderId;
    private String accountNumber;
    private String accountType;
    // getter and setter
}
```

This in AccountInfoMapper.xml

```
<select id="getAcountInfoById" parameterType="int" resultType="demo.domain.AccountInfo">
  select 
    *
  from 
    account_info
  where
    account_id = #{accountId}
</select>
```

This is test class

```
public class TestMybatisWithXML {
    private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        String resource = "config/myBatisConfig.xml";
        Reader inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
        sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(inputStream);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAcountInfoById() {
        SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
        AccountInfoMapper accountInfoMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(AccountInfoMapper.class);

        AccountInfo temAccountInfo = accountInfoMapper.getAcountInfoById(9);
        sqlSession.close();
        System.out.println(temAccountInfo.toString());
    }

}
```

Return from test class:

```
AccountInfo [accountId=9, accountHolderId=1, accountNumber=00010001, accountType=2]
```

This is what I would like to be the result instead:

```
AccountInfo [accountId=9, accountHolderId=1, accountNumber=00010001, accountType=credit]
```

If there are other different way I can have the same result it would be great. 
But this time, I could't modify database table or statements.

Creating a replacement map would also be acceptable.
But if there is some way in mybatis, may be better for me.

Comment: Please provide with concrete code samples,. the pseudo-code is unclear and may be interpreted in multiple ways.

If I try a guess: Your query returns a list of codes (int) and you need a list of objects whom property is the label matching this code? If you confirm that, I will write  resultHandler based solution.

Comment: I had edit my question.  Is there enough information? And thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case in the SQL query is an option as written by @Jorge Campos.

Another option would be to create a label table

```
CREATE TABLE account_type (
   account_type_id int(2) NOT NULL,
   account_type_name Varchar
)
```

and join in the select:

```
SELECT account_type_name AS account_type FROM account_info ai 
INNER JOIN account_type at ON ai.account_type=at.account_type_id
where account_id = #{accountId}
```

Or if you have account type id => label mapping in the java (property file, map ...), you can use *ResultHandler* to process the mapping.

The mapper signature becomes: `void getAcountInfoById(Integer id, ResultHandler rh);`

```
    final Map<Integer, String> labelMap = ...
    List<AccountInfo> accountInfoList = new ArrayList<>AccountInfo();
    ResultHandler<AccountInfo> rh = new ResultHandler() {
      public void handleResult(ResultContext<AccountInfo> resultContext) {
         AccountInfo accountInfo = getResultObject();
         accountInfo.setAccountType(labelMap.get(Integer.valueOf(accountInfo.getAccountType()));
         accountInfoList.add(accountInfo)
      }
    };
    accountInfoMapper.getAcountInfoById(id, rh);
```

Here I use a list as target, this applies when there are multiple results expected. You may use another object, the important is to provide a target to keep pointer(s) on the result(s).
Default (implicit) ResultHandler used by Mybatis actually fills a List, If you use your own, you have to fill the list yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No need for extra code or whatever. You just need a `CASE` statement on your query. It would be something like

```
<select id="getAcountInfoById" parameterType="int" resultType="demo.domain.AccountInfo">
  select 
    account_id, 
    account_holder_id, 
    account_number, 
    case when account_type=1 then 'debit' 
         when account_type=2 then 'credit' 
         when account_type=3 then 'affiliated'
         .... /*other conditions here*/
         end as account_type
  from 
    account_info
  where
    account_id = #{accountId}
</select>
```

That should be enough since the class attribute is already a `String`.

Comment: Very thankful for your advice and fix my grammar.Though this way, maybe  I need to modify a lot of queries statement , But it help me to fix another problem. :)